# Поменять строки таблицы местами

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Как поменять строки таблицы местами? Хотя бы код на JQuery, но можно и Drag and Drop

Comment: что имеется ввиду? "drag and drop"? [пример](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)

Comment: поменял немного вопрос... хорошая либа используется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) - вырезали нужную строку
2. [.insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) - вставили строку
3. Profit!

Comment: В примере для `.insertAfter()` эта команда переставляет местами два объекта http://jsfiddle.net/docd2vtq/

Comment: Почему то работает без detach(). Это нормально?

Comment: @sitev_ru, да да, jquery многое умеет.

Comment: было бы странно, если бы самая популярная javascript библиотека умела мало =)